# Dart Polymer: Removing element from DOM seems to be broken, when compiled to JS?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to remove a element from DOM, which was added via:

```dart
document.body.children.add(new DivElement()..innerHtml = "Hello World");
```

The code

```dart
document.body.children.remove(document.body.children.last);
```

or

```dart
document.body.children.removeLast();
```

works fine in Dartium but fails in Chrome when compiled to JS with an "Assertion failed"-Error. The failed assertion is: `assert(node instanceof Node);` and is placed in shadow_dom.debug.js:3364:5. It seems that the node to remove isn't an instance of Node?

Any workarounds for that? 
Dart SDK version is 1.2.0, Chrome version is 32.0.1700.76 m.

Comment: You could try `document.body.children[document.body.children.length -1].remove();` or add a debug output before this remove line that prints information about the last children.

Comment: Same error for 'document.body.children[document.body.children.length-1].remove();' Debug-output yields to: element != null -> true; element is Node -> true; element.parentNode -> body; element.id is equal to the id of added element.

Comment: I would file a bug at dartbug.com

Comment: Ok, thanks. Link is: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18065

Comment: I had trouble reproducing the bug. Can you post a reproduction to the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jmesserly on the bug:

> Ah, this is a known limitation from Shadow DOM. Try:
>
> ```
> document.querySelector('body')
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, from previous bugs filed on
>   https://github.com/polymer/ShadowDOM it is apparently not possible to
>   fix this in the polyfill.
>
> The only problematic members are directly accessing "document" and
>   navigating the tree. As soon as you call a method (like
>   querySelector), anything after that will work. If you use "body" a
>   lot, then try:
>
> ```
> final body = document.querySelector('body');
> ```